# How to get error AngularJS error messages from jsfiddle?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I have the following jsfiddle that I am trying to get working:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pz2L6etv/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function mainController($scope) {
    $scope.numbers = ['one','two','three'];
}

myApp.directive('uiCalendar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            message: "@theMessage",
            color: "@"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.color = scope.color === undefined ? 'black' : scope.color;
            $(element).append('<p style="color:'+scope.color+'">added this2: ' + scope.message + ' (' + scope.color + ')</p>');
        }
    };
});
```

It works locally but not at jsfiddle. But I don't see any error messages being shown in jsfiddle to help me debug it there, and my Firebug shows only jsfiddle-related information in the Console.

**How can I get jsfiddle to show me errors so I can debug my AngularJS code?**

Comment: the developer console? `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in firebug-lite.js`

Comment: and why are you using angular 1.0.1?

Comment: Also, `$(element)` is referencing jQuery, which isn't included in the jsfiddle.

Comment: FYI is easier to use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) than fiddle for angular sandbox. Has ability to simply add project files and has more angular versions available and does live reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually jsfiddle is outputting the errors right to the console, as expected. The problem is that one of your external resources is breaking execution before the angular code is run. Check it out, I forked your fiddle and removed that resource, and now the errors are output to the console just fine :)

```
function mainController($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = ['one','two','three'];
  console.log('hooray errors!');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7dguc1n/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## -- Latest for JSFiddle --

JSFiddle now has its own beta settings for displaying the console:

[image: Setting opened on JSFiddle to show console options]

which appears at the bottom of the results panel:

[image]